# Transaction lost? Output matches false

Tags: transaction-data

I have a transaction stuck anywhere. I sent it from my Binance to a brand new Monero GUI wallets new adress (not the primary). The deposite was sent **before** the wallet was ever connected with a remote node. Binance says "withdrawal sucessfull". The Monero GUI wallet says "Balance: 0" - and yes it is synced fully, resynced it three times - So after a long research I ended up on xmrscan.org. With all data entered the output matches were false. I know this is a problem and probably shows that the transaction is stuck, but can I get them back anyhow?

The whole story is about 72hrs ago.